# Create a List containing a dynamic number of Views with RecyclerVIew

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I want to show the user a **scrollable list of items which can each have a different number of "sub-views"**. For example:

[image]

My first idea was to create a RecyclerView that would inflate "items" that each contain their own RecyclerView:

Item:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/item">
    <TextView     
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nestedRecyclerView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I run into is that the *main* RecyclerView doesn't know the size of the *nested* one, and thus shows only the TextView above it, since it thinks that the height of the nested list is zero.

This can be somewhat fixed by setting a fixed layout:height to the nested list, but as shown on the item 3 of the example picture, the height may change depending on the number of items.

Is this the preferred way to create such a layout? If yes, how can I solve the "height" problem? If not, what would be the best method?

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by adding a gridview for the layout of the list adapter.

U would need to subclass gridview like below, which measures the child height properly.

```
public class NonScrollableGridView extends GridView {

public NonScrollableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
    // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
    int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
    getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

}